# How to detect the direction of a suggested route in MapBox Directions API?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am working on a project where I create an app that will direct users through a college campus using `AR` (Much like the one shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRmTn25xm7Q (7:20)).

I am starting off with the `Navigation API` for Android from `MapBox`. I want to know if there is any possible way to fetch a variable where the route guides you a direction(left, right, and forward) and put it through a parameter to prompt a UI element such as an arrow on AR screen in a `Unity Android Project`.

Here is my code from the Navigation API:

```
package com.creighton.adh81910.creighton_navigation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.view.SearchEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.DirectionsCriteria;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.MapboxDirections;
import com.mapbox.services.;
import com.mapbox.android.core.;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions.*;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.utils.LocaleUtils;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import android.util.Log;

import java.security.acl.Permission;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener {

private MapView mapView;
private MapboxMap map;
private Button startButton;
private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
private LocationEngine locationEngine;
private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
private Location originLocation;
private Point originPosition;
private Point destinationPosition;
private Marker destinationMarker;
private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
private MapboxDirections mapboxDirections;
private MapboxDirections.Builder directionsBuilder;

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Mapbox.getInstance(this, "pk.eyJ1IjoiYWRoYXJtYXZhcmFwdSIsImEiOiJjampzdXBkMW4wY25jM3BtcnUzNGpwdTA4In0.qN9Y1LoHxPaONtXLp7rBCw");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View v) {
boolean simulateRoute = true;
NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
.directionsRoute(currentRoute)
.shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
.build();
NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
}
});
// Example of a call to a native method
//TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
//tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
}

@override
public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
map = mapboxMap;
map.addOnMapClickListener(this);
enableLocation();
}

private void enableLocation() {
if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
initializeLocationEngine();
initializeLocationLayer();
} else {
permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
}
}

private void initializeLocationEngine() {
locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationEngine.activate();

Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
if (lastLocation != null) {
    originLocation = lastLocation;
    setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
} else {
    locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
}
}

private void initializeLocationLayer() {
locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
locationLayerPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
}

private void setCameraPosition(Location location) {
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 17));

}

@override
public void onMapClick(@nonnull LatLng point) {
destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originLocation.getLongitude(), originLocation.getLatitude());
getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);

startButton.setEnabled(true);
startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapbox_blue);
}

private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
NavigationRoute.builder(getApplicationContext())
.accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
.origin(origin)
.destination(destination)
.build()
.getRoute(new Callback() {
@override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
if (response.body() == null) {
Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, check right user and access token");
return;
} else if (response.body().routes().size() == 0) {
Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
return;
}
currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                    navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                } else {
                    navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                }

                navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}

@override
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public void onConnected() {
locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
}

@override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
if (location != null) {
originLocation = location;
setCameraPosition(location);
}
}

@override
public void onExplanationNeeded(List permissionsToExplain) {
//Present Dialog
}

@override
public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
if (granted) {
enableLocation();
}
}

@override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @nonnull String[] permissions, @nonnull int[] grantResults) {
permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
if (locationEngine != null) {
locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
}
if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
}
mapView.onStart();
}

@override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
mapView.onResume();
}

@override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
mapView.onPause();
}

@override
public void onStop() {
super.onStop();
if (locationEngine != null) {
locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
}
if (locationLayerPlugin != null) {
locationLayerPlugin.onStop();
}
mapView.onStop();
}

@override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (locationEngine != null) {
locationEngine.deactivate();
}
mapView.onDestroy();
}

@override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**

A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
which is packaged with this application.
*/
public native String stringFromJNI();
public static final class Builder {
private final MapboxDirections.Builder directionsBuilder;

private Builder() {
    directionsBuilder = MapboxDirections.builder();
}

public Builder Profile(@NonNull @DirectionsCriteria.ProfileCriteria String profile) {
    directionsBuilder.profile(profile);
    return this;
}

public static Builder builder(Context context) {
    return builder(context, new LocaleUtils());
}

static Builder builder(Context contect, LocaleUtils localeUtils) {
    return new Builder()
            .Profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING);
}
}
}
```